# Почему не работает max-width?

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, почему не работает свойство **max-width: 1650px;** для блока с классом "**header-wrapper**".

Я написал: max-width: 82.1% и всё заработало. Страница выглядит теперь так, как мне было и нужно:

[image]

Правда, когда сжимаешь страницу, то из зелёного блока **header-wrapper** почему-то "выпадает" меню:

[image]

Где-то я накосячил. Но не пойму где.

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

html{
 background: #03050b;
}


header{
 background: red;
}

.header-wrapper{
 background: green;
 max-width: 1650px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;

}

.header-wrapper img{
 width: 238px;

}

.menu{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
}

.menu li{
 padding-left: 50px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Merkury Landing Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <div class="header-wrapper">
    <img src="Images/Logo.png" alt="Логотип">
    <nav>
     <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="item">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="item">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="item">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="item">Contact</a></li>
      <li><div class="menu-item-btn">
       <a href="#">Login</a>
      </div></li>
     </ul>     
    </nav>
   </div>
  </header>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ваш код нормально работает при "сжатии" а точнее при уменьшении страницы, меню вылазит при масштабировании. вы же "сжимали" при помощи Ctrl + "+"? верно

Comment: @AB96 У вас просто места не хватает, что бы они вместились. к классу .menu вы дали display: flex; Поэтому меню не переходит на новую строку, но оно и не должно переходить. Не советую использовать процентную ширину для контейнера у десктопов, так будет легче верстать адаптивность. Например до 1650px окна браузера выставляете 1650px, потом следующий отрезок идёт до 1200 он будет 1200, потом 992px и c 767px уже ставите 100%, и там уже меню переходит в мобильное. Как-то так надо верстать. Вам таким образом нужно будет всего 4-5 состояний ширины окна браузера сверстать.

Answer (score 1):

Меню выпадает, так как элемент logo и li имеют фиксированный размер, в последнем случае - фиксированный отступ. В чем собственно проблема? Свойство max-width: 1650px работает как положено.

Comment: Спасибо. Разберусь с размером. Но свойство max-width: 1650px у блока с классом "header-wrapper" не работает. Работает там только max-width: 82.1%.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте убрать display: flex. Он делает ширину и высоту блока фиксированными под размер содержимого

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать отступы между li и добавить justify-content: space-between в родительский елемент.
Это распределит ваши елементы ровномерно плюс будет учитывать масштабирование.